# Using smartgit behind a proxy

Tags: windows, git, ssh, proxy

I'm working behind a company proxy (with credentials) for internet access and I'd like to reach a git repository hosted outside with smartgit for `windows`.

My repository is hosted `mygit.be`, my proxy is at `10.30.30.30` on port `8080` with user `toto` and `mygit.be` is accessible via `ssh` on port `25000` with user `git` and `private key authentication`.

After lot of searches on internet, I added a `HOME` environment variable pointing to `c:\Users\toto\`.  I also copied my private key in `c:\Users\toto\.ssh`.  And finally, I created a `config` file in `c:\Users\toto\.ssh` containing

```
Host mygit.be
  ProxyCommand connect -H toto@10.30.30.30:8080 %h 25000
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git
```

Now using

```
c:\Program Files\SmartGit\git\bin\git.exe ls-remote ssh://git@mygit.be:25000/~/myrepository.git refs/heads/*
```

is working fine. It's asking me the proxy password then gives me the result.

```
Enter proxy authentication password for toto@10.30.30.30:
b21e99487808231c992d50ca6bef483bea788708        refs/heads/dev
5021a3be4be18dbdb80f6ce2a01a7ca780862c30        refs/heads/master
```

My problem is now to have all that working within smartgit.

I configured it to use system ssh.  But on the clone dialog, after the first 'Next' button, it hangs on `Checking connection to repository` without never asking me the proxy password.

So, what's the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is quite simple.

**First solution**

It is needed to add a `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable containing

```
git gui--askpass
```

Now smartgit will ask for the proxy password.

The only remaining is problem is that smartgit will ask very often the password.

**Second solution**

Create a dos batch file passwd.bat containing

```
@echo mypassword
```

then back to solution one and the SSH_ASKPASS vairiable now contains

```
path-to-bat-file\passwd.bat
```